# NFL head coach with no previous NFL, CFL or college coaching experience?

Tags: american-football, nfl

The Indianapolis Colts just [announced](https://www.colts.com/news/jeff-saturday-hired-interim-head-coach-pro-bowl-center-espn) that Jeff Saturday will be their interim head coach. Saturday's only coaching experience is with a high school team. In the Super Bowl era (since 1967) has there ever been a head coach appointed with absolutely no coaching experience at the NFL, CFL or college level? I only found coaches with no NFL experience (but plenty of college experience) like Urban Meyer or Chip Kelly. Even coaches hired in their 30s (like Sean McVay) seem to have years of NFL experience as coordinator, position coach or assistant before getting a head coach job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jeff Saturday is the first head coach to be hired to the NFL with no college or professional coaching experience since [Norm Van Brocklin](https://profootballtalk.nbcsports.com/2022/11/07/jeff-saturday-becomes-first-head-coach-with-no-college-or-pro-coaching-experience-in-61-years/) of the Minnesota Vikings in 1961.

Van Brocklin was the last former player with no college or pro coaching experience to become head coach before the Jeff Saturday hire.